# Is it possible to withdraw USD from an ATM in Nairobi, Kenya?

Tags: money, nairobi

While in Nairobi I might need to top up my supply of USD. Is it possible to get it directly from an ATM or will I need to go to a currency exchange?

Comment: I couldn't find any, but according to @shnozolla response there is one. Anyway you can get USD from banks or exchange offices in Nairobi.

Comment: The KCB at the Village Market, near the UN Headquarters in Nairobi also offers up to 300 USD.

Comment: Keep in mind that the reliability of ATMs is extremely low in East Africa, even if you're only trying to withdraw local currency. Count on trying several ATMs before you find one that works at all.

Comment: @BenCrowell have you been to Kenya? Because I haven never experienced the problems with ATMs you are talking about.

Comment: It is possible to withdraw any currency (USD) UERO etc in Nairobi Kenya. I have done many withdraws in KCB and Banklays Bank for USD withdraws. Its really interesting.

Comment: And what about at the airports?

Comment: Any limit on how much you can withdraw in USD?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, I have successfully withdrawn USD from KCB in Nairobi a couple of times.
Here is the location I have done this: http://goo.gl/maps/fvojb

Comment: Was this with a local or an international card?

Comment: @AndrewWidgery This was using a US local bank card (I used a bank of america debit card, and a chase debit card)

Comment: @shnozolla what were the fees like?

Answer (score 6):

There is rumor that there is at least one ATM with an USD cash option:

> I found one KCB ATM (across from main post office in Nairobi) which gives you the choice to withdraw in KSH or US dollars.

Source: [Lonely Planet](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2119083)

Drop a line here if you could confirm it!

Answer (score 5):

So this has been an issue for quite a while. Fortunately here is a local who withdraws USDs from local ATM every week.
FYI I use a Bank of America ATM

```
KCB University way ATM @ Anniversary towers (1 machine)
KCB Kipande House ATM (1 machine)
KCB Kencom ATM (2 machines)
```

Bienividos Kenya!

Answer (score 4):

Though it seems [every answer is equally valid](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) they might benefit from some organisation:

```
Date     User       Where                                   Notes 
20121019 Dan        KCB across from main post office    
20121115 shnozolla  KCB                                     US local bank card
20130416 user6326   KCB Village Market near UN Headquarters up to 300 USD
20141128 mark       the mall                                withdrawn US $1000
20150603 Danny      KCB Univerity way Anniversary towers    1 machine
                    KCB Kipande House                       1 machine
                    KCB Kencom                              2 machines
20150808 Bradley    KCB Karen Shopping centre   
         Gibbs      
20160302 Mark       TRM 2nd flour   
20160901 Lawrence   I&M bank Gigiri near WarWick building   
         Kimani     KCB Sarit Centre    
                    JKIA                                    3 ATMS
                    TRM                                     1
20170209 Kelvin     KCB and Banklays Bank                   also UERO
         Jackson
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a USD atm at the KCB Kipandi House (across the road from the post office) but when I went there on 2/8/15 it was out of order. It is the one on a the far right as you enter (ones with USD are not labelled). I cannot confirm the one at Anniversary towers as I went there on a Sunday and could not get access to the ATMS. I was told by locals there we one at kencom. I could not see one providing USD when I went there. I only checked the atms on the northern side though. There may still be something there as it is the main office for KCB.

I ended up being able to get 1000 USD from the KCB atm at Karen Shopping centre. It is the one on the right. This is the closes atm for all those starting overland tours from Karen Camp. I heard that other people could only get 300 USD from this one so it may depend on your own bank.

Also the KCB at Moyale does not give USD

Answer (score 3):

Yeah! Nowadays it is possible to withdrawal dollars in Kenya ATMs, You can get these services from I&M bank at Gigiri near WarWick building, several KCB ATMS such as two in Kencom but you need to ask the soldier there to show you, 1 in Kipande house, 1 in Sarit Centre, 3 ATMS in the JKIA and 1 in TRM.

Comment: Great first answer, welcome to TSE.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to post an update since many of these answers are years old.

I tried one KCB ATM at "The Mall" at Westlands,  it did not have dollars.

I found this website has a list of I&M bank ATMs that dispense dollars: https://www.imbankgroup.com/ke/atms_category/us-dollar-dispensing-atms/

The I&M ATM at [Yaya Center](https://goo.gl/maps/tuJYrXwvwSkDtBHc7) worked for me. It has a limit of $2000. It did not charge me any ATM fees, but maybe it has to do with an agreement with my own international bank? Not sure.

Note that your bank may have a different ATM limit that is lower. You can call them to have them temporarily raise your ATM limit for 24 hours.

Here's a photo, the ATM had signs about dispensing dollars
[image: ATM that dispenses dollars]

Answer (score 2):

I have successful withdrawn US $1000 from KCB ATM at the mall in Nairobi, Kenya.

Comment: For completeness' sake do you remember which mall? How long ago was it?

Comment: There's a mall called "The Mall" in the Westlands district of Nairobi 

https://goo.gl/maps/hTqGuU3GUq8QRL6z9 @JoErNanO

Answer (score 2):

There is a KCB ATM at TRM 2nd flour adjacent to KCB Bank in the mall where you can withdraw USD